# HTTP proxy implementation: content encoding error

Tags: c, proxy

I am implementing an proxy. I could receive response from server, but failed to send the response to client.

To be more detail, I could only rend response header content, but failed to send message body. And webpage shows'content encoding error'

```
    //I could sending request to server successfully.
    send(connfd_to_server, request, strlen(request), 0);

    //receive response from server
    char res_buf[1024];
    while(1){
        bzero(res_buf, 1024);
        if(recv(connfd_to_server, res_buf, sizeof(res_buf),0) <=0){
            break; //if recv failed, then message body is finished.
        }  //receive response using recv
        send(connfd_to_client, res_buf, strlen(res_buf));
    }
```

[image: Here is what I got, header is sent to client successfully, but following message body is not]

I also tried:

```
char* response = (char*)malloc(strlen(res_buf));
char* res_line;
res_line = strtok(res_buf, "\r\n");
for(int i = 0; i<=11; i++){
     strcat(response, res_line);
     strcat(response, "\r\n");
     res_line = strtok(NULL, "\r\n");
}    //copy header content using strcat

while(res_line!= NULL){
    memcpy(response, res_line, sizeof(res_line));
    res_line = strtok(NULL, "\r\n");
}   //copy message body as bytes using memcpy

then send response to client using send function.
```

However, no matter which function I use, message body are not send successfully.
like shown in a weird symbol above
Any hints?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The function recv returns the number of bytes read which you could use when calling function send.

You used strlen which is based on detecting a null character to find the end of the buffer, which in this case is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Content encoding says gzip so the data coming from server will have binary data in its http response body which may also contain null character so you may end up sending partial data, as you have used `strlen()` in `send()`, that your client will not be able to decode

Comment: Right! I got it!  However, how about memcpy()? I also tried to copy message body using memcpy()? I think memcpy() can copy response bytes by bytes. Why it doesn't work we asll? Could you help me?

Comment: In your send() call just use the value returned by recv() instead of doing strlen() on received data